# Golang producer channels as parameter or as return value

Tags: go, channel

As far as I know there are two ways of handling producer channels within functions: (1) as parameter or (2) as return value. While for (1) the function is the owner of the channel, the owner in (2) is unknown (for the function.

What is more idiomatic, `producer1` or `producer2`? Did I oversee a disadvantage? Are there any specific use scenarios?

Here are the implementation of (1) and (2):

```
func producer1(numbers []int) <-chan int {
    out := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        defer close(out)
        for _, n := range numbers {
            out <- n
        }
    }()
    return out
}

func producer2(numbers []int, out <-chan int) {
    go func() {
        defer close(out)
        for _, n := range numbers {
            out <- n
        }
    }()
}
```

Comment: You can use both buffered or non-buffered channel with producer2 while producer1 always uses the latter.

Comment: @MarcinZawiejski: Hi, you may use buffered and non-buffered channel with both: see [buffered](https://play.golang.org/p/-pk89TdNBwk) and [non-buffered](https://play.golang.org/p/Xm8h8_i4Z13).

Comment: @A.R Of course you can if you modify the producer1 code (as you did in the "buffered" link) but the question is for the specific implementation where you can't use buffered channels with producer1

Answer (score 6):

IMHO : it depends.

`producer1` is very explicit about this channel's behavior and lifetime (which can be a good thing),
`producer2` allows you to plug the emission of these values in some greater context (which can also be a good thing).

The notion of "good thing" actually depends on how you intend to use these channels outside of these functions.

---

One extra remark : `producer2` does not handle the channel's creation, I would also remove the line which closes the channel from this function.

If you want to know whether producer2 has completed its task, you may use some other way to signal this, for example :

```
func producer2(numbers []int, out <-chan int) (done <-chan struct{}) {
    done = make(chan struct{})

    go func() {
        defer close(done)
        for _, n := range numbers {
            out <- n
        }
    }()

    return done
}

// a caller may check '<-done' to see if producer2 has finished feeding all
// of its numbers into the 'out' channel
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `ch := producer1([]int{1, 2, 3, 4})` simplifies these two lines:

```
out := make(chan int)
producer2([]int{10, 20, 30, 40}, out)
```

into one line:

```
ch := producer1([]int{1, 2, 3, 4})
```

So first use case is code **simplification** ([DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)), when you need it many times.

> What is more idiomatic, `producer1` or `producer2`?

for your example use case `producer1`

> Did I oversee a disadvantage?

Yes

> Are there any specific use scenarios?

[DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

---

Note: in `producer2` you must use tx only channel like this `out chan<- int` instead of `out <-chan int` (rx only channel).
like this working code (Run [buffered](https://play.golang.org/p/aCCE7__LSrJ) and [non-buffered](https://play.golang.org/p/Xm8h8_i4Z13)):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func producer1(numbers []int) <-chan int {
    out := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        defer close(out)
        for _, n := range numbers {
            out <- n
        }
    }()
    return out
}

func main() {
    ch := producer1([]int{1, 2, 3, 4})
    for v := range ch {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
    out := make(chan int)
    producer2([]int{10, 20, 30, 40}, out)
    for v := range out {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}

func producer2(numbers []int, out chan<- int) {
    go func() {
        defer close(out)
        for _, n := range numbers {
            out <- n
        }
    }()
}
```